# jsf - spring - hibernate transaction management

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I'm having trouble figuring the best way to manage transactions in a jsf - spring - hibernate situation. What clued me in was I got the following error message:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: [class name], no session or session was closed
```

My managed bean called the spring bean which did a call to the dao which uses hibernate and retrieved a collection that had a one-to-many relationship. When I tried to examine the collections I got the error (I know that if I traverse the collection in the dao that will preserve the data but I want to go beyond that).

Here is the managed bean code:

```
@Transactional
private void loadAppointments() {

  employees = userService.getEmployees();

}
```

(Note: It is when I try and traverse employees that I get the error.)

Here is the spring bean call:

```
public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return getUserDAO().getEmployees();
}
```

and here is the dao code:

```
List<Employee> employees = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(" from Employee ").list();
return new HashSet<Employee>(employees);
```

here is part of my applicationContext.xml relating to transactions:

```
<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
   <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I'm not sure why the @Transactional annotation failed in the Spring bean, could someone explain it to me?

One person recommended using JPATransactionManager, but I have no experience with it and I was wondering if anyone else had any recommendations.
What's the best / easiest way to control a transaction from my Spring bean? Is there an article or something which lays out the options? This seems to be a fairly dense subject so all help appreciated.

Edit:
    
    
        
        
            
                com.dave.model.User
                com.dave.model.Client
                com.dave.model.Appointment
                com.dave.model.Employee
                com.dave.model.Certificate
            
        
        
            
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                true

Comment: Judging by the error message this is a Hibernate session management issue, not a Transaction management issue.  What strategy are you using to manage your Hibernate sessions?

Comment: I'm a newbie. What you see above is what you get. Would you suggest anything?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of SessionFactory bean in applicationContext.xml file?

Comment: That is the transaction manager declaration. Where is the bean sessionFactory defined?